# Vue ref change does not apply changes to the component after update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I have a form implemented with vue3. The form consists of three text inputs and a checkbox group.

I am using bootstrap-vue form and it's checkbox-group for this.

I call an api to set default values on the form, after the api responds I update the ref like the code below and **all three text inputs get updated just fine**.

The problem is with the checkbox group component. **The checked items won't get checked although they are inside of the tagList ref.**

```
// I set the formValues ref and api call to get default values in this composable.
// taglist will be a list of strings: tagList = ['example']
  const formValues = ref<IArticleFormValues>({
    title: '',
    body: '',
    description: '',
    tagList: [],
  });

  const { data, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['fetchArticleBySlug', slug],
    queryFn: () => fetchSingleArticleService(slug)
  });

  watch(data, () => {
    if (data.value?.article) {
      formValues.value = {
        ...data.value.article,
        tagList: data.value.article.tagList.map((item) => item),
      };
    }
  });

// I then inject this data using vue inject like this
provide(formInjectionKey, {  formValues });
```

Here is the checkbox-group component. tags is just another list of options in this format.

`tags =  [{text:'example',value:'example'}]`

also tagList will be like this.

`tagList = ['example']`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import CustomCheckboxGroup from '@/components/DesignSystem/components/CustomCheckboxGroup.vue';
import { inject } from 'vue';

const { formValues } = inject(formInjectionKey);

</script>

<template>
<CustomCheckboxGroup v-else :options="tags" v-model="formValues.tagList" />
</template>
```

And here is the CustomCheckboxGroup component.

```
// CustomCheckboxGroup.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{ value?: any[]; options: any[] }>();
</script>

<template>
  <b-form-group>
    <b-form-checkbox-group
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event)"
      :options="options"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      stacked
    ></b-form-checkbox-group>
  </b-form-group>
</template>
```

Comment: try `:checked="value"` instead of `:value="value"`

Comment: @yoduh That worked thank you. Post it as an answer and I will accept it as correct.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you.  Answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox inputs use a different prop for setting their checked value.
Use `:checked="value"` instead of `:value="value"`